# Creating your own packages using Chocolatey

Tags: windows, nuget, package-managers, chocolatey

I am trying to create a package with Chocolatey for an application called [Listary](http://www.listary.com). I have followed the instructions on the [Chocolatey wiki](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CreatePackages) and also the article [here](http://blog.denizac.org/2012/06/creating-your-first-package-with.html).

I have also created an account on http://chocolatey.org and set up the API key using

> nuget setApiKey  -Source http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/

where &ltapiKey> is replaced with your API key.

When I entered the command `choco pack` to create the NuGet package, it said **Successfully created package**, but when I test the package that I just created using **cinst Listary -source Listary.1.0.nupkg -force** it says

```
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Command 'install' failed (sometimes this indicates a partial failure). Additional info/packages: Listary
```

This is what I have in my **Listary.nuspec** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Listary</id>
    <title>Listary</title>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authors>Zhenheng Dai</authors>
    <owners>Zhenheng Dai</owners>
    <summary>Keep files at your fingertips. Listary is a unique search utility for Windows.</summary>
    <description>Listary is a unique search utility for Windows. Not only does it make file browsing truly flexible -- thanks to its multi-file managers support -- but the ultra-compact UI also redefines minimalism. The lightweight design doesn't stop it from providing various advanced features however, that may fit the needs of both casual and power users alike. All you have to do is just type the file name that you’re looking for, and Listary will display the search results at breakneck speed.</description>
    <projectUrl>http://www.listary.com</projectUrl>
    <tags>listary search find filemanager admin</tags>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="tools\**" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

and the **chocolateyInstall.ps1** contains the following.

```
$packageName = 'Listary'
$installerType = 'exe'
$url = 'http://www.listary.com/download/Listary.exe'
$silentArgs = '/SP /VERYSILENT /NORESTART'
Install-ChocolateyPackage "$packageName" "$installerType" "$silentArgs" "$url"
```

Comment: API key setting in choco 0.9.9+ is `choco apikey` and no longer uses nuget configuration at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CreatePackages#testing-your-package
(fixed link)

Note the source is not a nupkg but rather a directory where the nupkg file is found.

In choco.exe (the reincarnation of Chocolatey), you can simply point to a nuspec or a nupkg file for install.

Comment: When I run the command `cinst Listary -source %cd% -force` in the directory where the nupkg package resides, I get `Unable to find package 'Listary'.`

Comment: As the full path to which the package resides contained spaces, I needed to enclose it with quotes, so I needed to run the command `cinst Listary -source "%cd%" -force`. I have successfully uploaded the package which you can find at http://chocolatey.org/packages/listary

Comment: Yeah, using the quotes will help, too! :)

Comment: I had a similar problem and I needed to put the package title in quotes since the title had spaces.

Comment: Use `-s .` \ `--source .` - works for both cmd.exe and powershell.exe.